# How can I create a testable hypotheses to compare benchmark results for the same tests run in 3 environments

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am planning on running the same benchmark tests (i.e. throughput, response time,..) in 3 environments: 1) a mobile device, 2) a virtual machine in VirtualBox, 3) a virtual machine on Amazon EC2.

What could be the best way to define the hypothesis, Null or Alternate when considering significant differences or relations between the means obtained from the test runs?

Comment: The most obvious answer is probably to run the test as many times as you can in each environment, then test the null that the means of all three samples are equal with an ANOVA (possibly using a generalized linear model depending on the error distribution)...Alternately, equivalence testing would allow you to falsify the null that they are different, if that's what you want to do...but in the end, I agree with @Dennis' assessment and recommendations.

Comment: @Nick, thanks for great response and advice, will investigate this approach

Answer (score 3):

Don't do hypothesis testing.  It's only going to tell you what you already know: they are different.  Quantify the differences in your response variable(s) across the environment.  You can do it in a Bayesian way with HPD or credible intervals, or in a frequentist way with a confidence interval.

Comment: great advice, will investigate this approach